# Xtion with diamondback?

Tags: xtion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does ASUS Xtion work with ROS diamondback ? I have been trying to work with Xtion Pro on ROS diamondback (1.4.10) installed on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with no success !

**This is the error I am getting** : http://answers.ros.org/question/30700/open-ni-glibc_212-not-found

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31791/xtion-with-diamondback-?/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2012-04-13

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-16**:
Please provide the errors you are getting. http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-04-17**:
@tfoote Updated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Xtion is not supported in Diamondback. Use [openni_launch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch) available in Electric and Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1